# Recognize that I am not on a git tag with bash

Tags: bash, git, shell

I would like to have a bash script that will recognize if the caller is not on a git tag (but on an un tagged branch e.g.). I tried the following:

```
OUTPUT=$(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')|grep "fatal:")
if [[ $OUTPUT != "0" ]]; then
    echo "no tag present"
fi
```

but I get `no tag present` even if there clearly is a tag and the print out of `git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')` does not contain **fatal:**. Why does this not work as expected?

Comment: Without even looking at the Git commands: since you're piping to `grep "fatal:"` at the end, your string will always either contain `fatal:` or be empty, but it will never be `0`, so the condition is always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to rely on the exit status of that command:

```
if ! git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h') 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "no tag present"
fi
```

If there is no tag, the exit status is 128.
If there is, the exist status is 0.

[jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706703/recognize-that-i-am-not-on-a-git-tag-with-bash/62708509#comment110894002_62708509):

```
if msg=`git describe --exact-match --tags @ 2>&1`; then 
    echo tagged $msg; 
else 
    echo not tagged; 
fi
```

---

Note that `--no-exact-match` also exist, and Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) test it.

See [commit c95ae3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c95ae3ff9cdcbe6229dc3aa4cd7aa14b1354759a) (21 Jul 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3085f94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3085f949bf4aafe04dac7441308bb769ccf9c351), 28 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`describe`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c95ae3ff9cdcbe6229dc3aa4cd7aa14b1354759a): fix `--no-exact-match`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Since [2c33f75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c33f7575452f53382dcf77fdc88a2ea5d46f09d) ("Teach [`git-describe --exact-match`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2c33f7575452f53382dcf77fdc88a2ea5d46f09d/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> to avoid expensive tag searches", 2008-02-24, Git v1.5.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6a7c606a6fb89f51258d2a60bc27cfe2530a0a1)) [`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c95ae3ff9cdcbe6229dc3aa4cd7aa14b1354759a/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> accepts `--no-exact-match`, but it does the same as `--exact-match`, an alias for `--candidates=0`.
> That's because it's defined using `OPT_SET_INT` with a value of 0, which sets 0 when negated as well.
>
> Let `--no-exact-match` set the number of candidates to the default value instead.
> Users that need a more specific lack of exactitude can specify their preferred value using `--candidates`, as before.
>
> Also add a case where `--exact-match` option is used on a commit that cannot be described without distance from tags and make sure the command fails.

Comment: ``if msg=`git describe --exact-match --tags @ 2>&1`; then echo tagged $msg; else echo not tagged; fi``

Comment: @jthill Good alternative: no need to redirect stdout, since it is capture in the msg variable indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Can I recommend [`git tag --points-at`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---points-atltobjectgt)? For example in [one of my repositories](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject): commit [b0b1c9c](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/commit/b0b1c9c3610f9b52ea80c815a93cf49241081497) is [tagged](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/releases/tag/3.8.0) but the `HEAD` is not:

```
$ git tag --points-at b0b1c9c
3.8.0
$ git tag --points-at
(empty)
```

So you can use test

```
if [ -z "$(git tag --points-at)" ]; then
    echo "no tag present"
fi
```

Comment: @VonC Ok, changed, tnx!